# Getting facebook deeplinks to work on emulator facebook android

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-emulator

The problem I'm trying to solve- I'm trying to get deep linking working, and testing it with Emulator. When clicking on posts, the links direct to the mobile web site. This is in the case of the user having permissions for the app, and the app is installed (on the emulator). In the Facebook app, it even acknowledges its out of date, but an upgrade (in app) crashes.

I also noticed that the Facebook app installed on the emulator is out of date (I installed it  via `adb install facebook.apk` from github sdk).

SSO is working fine, and I have setup deeplinking effectively with iOS before (So I know how ti's supposed to work/test it, etc.). But the port to Android is being held back by this out of date 3rd party Facebook app. I'm assuming testing on device will solve it, because there the Facebook app will be the latest (which brings to mind- what if people haven't updated their android facebook app?).

My app settings:
[image: facebook app settings]

I'd post code, but this seems to be pure integration and configuration issues.

Note: my app isn't published on Google Play, could that be the issue?
Also: maybe this is only testable on the device? My device is "in the mail" so trying to get this done with emulator as much as i can.

Update: Facebook told me that this requires the Facebook app 1.9.* which is not in the SDK. So, I got my hands on a device, and while I haven't solved it, at least the app bookmark functionality is working. Will update if/when I find the answer.

Update 11am: I finally got it to work!

1. I had to publish my app in the Play/Market.
2. Each time I tested, log out of FB-Android app, clear cache, and force stop. Acc.
   to the documentation the bookmarks are cached. I also think the
   facebook app-syncing occurs on launch, and never again. So if you
   change anything in FB's app settings, you need to log out/clear
   cache/stop for it to take in the fb android app.
3. Only one key worked, even though it says "hash" in the fb app settings, I think
   my dev key was screwing things up. Double-confirm that your release
   key is the same as the one listed in app settings.
4. The final secret sauce for me, was to turn off SSO and deeplinking, re-test
   without anything set. Also, remove dev package from phone and
   download from Play. (see: key mixups).  then, I stepped back through
   the configurations by first turning on SSO, testing, then turning on
   the native deep linking.
5. Only works on real device, not emulator (unless you can get 1.9 installed on emulator, may work, did not go down that route to test)
6. Not sure if this matters, but it may: install app from Store/Play, not from Eclipse. Could be the key syncing thing.

Comment: Just for clarification: the _problem_ is that the mobile site (I'm assuming the main page) is opening instead of the desired non-mobile page?

Comment: Yes- deeplinking isn't working, in that it's not launching my app, just going to mobile web.   I guess it's a twofold problem because I would also like the most recent facebook.apk in my emulator, and I can't find it, nor upgrade through the emulator.

Comment: If you construct an emulator with the Google APIs, you could use the Android Market to the get the latest Facebook app to test that hypothesis. I suspect it isn't the app version, though. If you watch the adb logs, does anything interesting show up?

Comment: adb logcat displays: I/ActivityManager(   58): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://www.banane.com/lyrics/?newword=blue cmp=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity } - looks like it's starting the browser, there's no app setup for loading the app. Which makes me think it's a configuration issue.

Comment: OK just tested the posted link with the iPhone and it does launch in-app. I was doing that to test the link formation. Unless Android's Facebook app is a lot pickier.

Comment: Just tested with a signed apk of my app, made sure the key was in the app settings, and still went to mobile web.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out- involved doing the following:

1. I had to publish my app in the Play/Market.
2. Each time I tested, log out of FB-Android app, clear cache, and force stop. Acc. to the documentation the bookmarks are cached. I also think the facebook app-syncing occurs on launch, and never again. So if you change anything in FB's app settings, you need to log out/clear cache/stop for it to take in the fb android app.
3. Only one key worked, even though it says "hash" in the fb app settings, I think my dev key was screwing things up. Double-confirm that your release key is the same as the one listed in app settings.
4. The final secret sauce for me, was to turn off SSO and deeplinking, re-test without anything set.  Also, remove dev package from phone and download from Play. (see: key mixups). then, I stepped back through the configurations by first turning on SSO, testing, then turning on the native deep linking.
5. Only works on real device, not emulator (unless you can get 1.9 installed on emulator, may work, did not go down that route to test)
6. Not sure if this matters, but it may: install app from Store/Play, not from Eclipse. Could be the key syncing thing.

Comment: Update: Facebook is fixing this bug- they're deploying a more recent emulator Facebook app in the SDK.

Comment: Facebook's Android SDK now ships with an apk you can install on the emulator : FBAndroid-2.1.apk

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at the [troubleshooting tips for deep linking](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/deep_linking/#deeplink)? (Sorry, have to ask.)

I'm wondering if perhaps the FB app on your device was not properly quit after the relevant setting changes.

Comment: I did "force stop" the Facebook app in Manage Applications, after I added the latest key, and it still opened to Mobile web. BTW: "When you make app settings changes, be sure to 'force quit' the Facebook App so it will reload the Bookmark from its cache" -- there are no app bookmarks in the Facebook app that ships with the android-facebook-sdk. It's an old version that just shows feed stories, not a list of apps & bookmarks.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe the old version just doesn't support deep links. Did you try getting the fresh one from Google Play?

Comment: Correct- anything before 1.9 doesn't support deep links. I was on an emulator and couldn't get the latest facebook app. But then, got my hands on a device. Still, lots of little quirks to configuring to get it to work.

Comment: If you find yourself in a similar situation again, it is possible to create an emulator with Google Play on it. Just pick a target with the Google APIs, it'll include Play and Maps etc. Then you have access to anything on Play, including Facebook.

Comment: I've got Google API's installed but don't see Market, am I missing something? Android version 4.0.3 / 15. I see maps, and other API stuff but no Play/Market

Comment: My bad, I forgot that it's only built in with the APIs for hardware builds (which is what I usually work with). You'll need to install the apk for it to get it in an emulator, like here: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/10004/accessing-android-market-from-android-sdk/ , but that is a lot of work. I'm surprised that there isn't a cleaner solution for FB devs. You'd think there'd be enough of them to warrant the attention.

Comment: I added a bug w/ FB to ship the most current version. IMHO that's lame of them to have an old 1.5 (vs. 1.9) apk in their sdk.